# Changing Schema in GBQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, schema

I manually created a duration field in excel which calculates a time duration between a start date and end date and formatted it as HH:MM:SS. When I upload this in Google Big query it appears as a string. Then I used a CAST function

```
SELECT CAST (ride_length AS INTERVAL)
```

to change the type from `STRING` to `INTERVAL` and got the following error

> Invalid INTERVAL value '0.00:22:28'

I need to change the data type to a number so I can calculate maximum, minimum, and average duration. GBQ doesn't let me do that with a string data type.

```
SELECT CAST (ride_length AS INTERVAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below:

```
WITH
  sampleData AS(
  SELECT
    '01:05:07' AS duration
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '02:05:07' AS duration
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '04:05:07' AS duration ),

    
  sample AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(duration AS TIME FORMAT 'HH24:MI:SS') AS duration2
  FROM
    sampleData --converts string to time format
    )


SELECT
  MAX(duration2) AS MAXTIME,
  MIN(duration2) AS MINTIME,
   TIME(
     EXTRACT(hour   FROM AVG(duration2 - '0:0:0')), 
     EXTRACT(minute FROM AVG(duration2 - '0:0:0')), 
     EXTRACT(second FROM AVG(duration2 - '0:0:0'))
   ) as AVERAGE from
  sample;
```

This is given that your sample's format are accepted by BigQuery, See the sample output below for getting Max, Min, Average:

[image]

***UPDATE:***
Additional Code (for better readability, just change the names appropriate to your table ):

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(yourfieldName AS TIME FORMAT 'HH24:MI:SS') AS duration
  FROM
    yourTableId --converts string to time format
    )


SELECT
  MAX(duration) AS MAXTIME,
  MIN(duration) AS MINTIME,
   TIME(
     EXTRACT(hour   FROM AVG(duration - '0:0:0')), 
     EXTRACT(minute FROM AVG(duration - '0:0:0')), 
     EXTRACT(second FROM AVG(duration - '0:0:0'))
   ) as AVERAGE from
  sample;
```

Comment: Hi, this would work but I have thousands of fields in the duration column. Is there anyway to do it without having to manually enter every data point?

Comment: You should probably delete the ```sampleData``` clause and change the ```duration``` to your column name. I will try to add an update and see if it works additionally you can update your inquiry and add sample data and expected output that will help the community to replicate your steps for this question.

Comment: Ok thanks noted. I got the following error when I ran your query - Failed to parse input timestamp string at 1 with format element ':'

Comment: I see, This is probably you have a decimal on your hours on your data(0.00:22:28) Im not entirely sure why is this format but you can try changing the cast parameter to this ```(duration AS TIME FORMAT 'HH24.FF2:MI:SS')``` as you can see I added .FF2 this will work as long as all of your data is following the format  of your initial data with decimals (0.00:22:28)  alternatively you can change the format of your data to make the hours to whole number in your excel file then upload it on BQ.